# What does it mean to have sacred / ancestral aspects?

Tags: diablo-iv

As my level increases, I'm starting to find some sacred/ancestral versions of aspects. However, for the vast majority of aspects, it seems to make no difference what version it is, for example (click to zoom):

[image: Sacred aspect of disobedience] [image: Ancestral aspect of disobedience]

(in fact, the ancestral one could be said to be worse as it has the same effect but requires higher minimum level)

Does the aspect tier actually matter for anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean to have sacred / ancestral aspects?

This depends on if the aspect was obtained by destroying a sacred or ancestral item.

> Does the aspect tier actually matter for anything?

It depends. For some items, as shown, it does not make a difference. However, there are other items where the range does make a difference, and that is in places where applied damage is being used.

For example, with the Sorcerer you can use the Aspect of the Frozen Tundra: *"While Deep Freeze is active, exploding Ice Spikes form in the area, dealing [X] Cold damage. Your Ice Spikes have a [30-40%] increased explosion radius."*. An aspect from a level 30 item versus an aspect from an ancestral level 80 item will have a significant difference in the [X] Cold damage range (not just the roll in that range, the actual min to max numbers).